# Should I import a python module if I don't use it directly

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am working on a project with a few files, and one of my helper modules has a function that takes as argument a [criterion that measures MSE from the torch library](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.MSELoss.html). This module does postprocessing (displaying/saving plots and saving relevant data) and doesn't explicitly use any functionality from torch other than using the passed criterion to compute the mean squared error for two of the parameters.

Is it best practice to import torch, or is it ok not to? Similarly, should I import numpy when dealing implicitly with numpy arrays?

Here is the code in question:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# use latex for plt labels/diagrams
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')

columns_tex = [r'$x$ (m)', r'$\dot{x}$ (m/s)', r'$\theta$ (rad)', r'$\dot{\theta}$ (rad/s)']
columns_file = ['x', 'x_dot', 'theta', 'theta_dot']

def process_plots(test_y, predicted_y, total_error, criterion, system, m, displaying_plots, saving_plots):
    '''
    m: number of training examples
    '''
    for i, col in enumerate(columns_tex):
        # criterion is given by torch.nn.MSELoss()
        mse = criterion(test_y[:,i],predicted_y[:,i])
        error = total_error[:,i].detach().numpy() # plt.scatter complains about being passed torch tensor
        plt.scatter([j for j in range(len(test_y))], error, s=1)
        plt.ylabel(f"{col} error: exp - actual")
        plt.xlabel(r'prediction $i$')
        plt.title(f"mean squared error for predictions of {col} at t+1 is {mse}", pad=20)
        plt.tight_layout()
        if saving_plots:
            plt.savefig(f'./data/processed/imgs/torch_lin_reg/{system}/{columns_file[i]}_error_{m}')
        if displaying_plots:
            plt.show()
        plt.clf()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `python` compiler figures out if you already imported `pytorch` and won't import it a second time. In this case, if you want it to potentially run separately by a script that doesn't `import torch`, better add it at the beginning since it should be ignored anyways if it's not necessary.

Comment: The file is run by two different scripts, one that doesn't require `torch` and another that does. I don't want to import it unnecessarily, though I guess the overhead can't be too much. Regardless, thanks for your answer.